# Oxyplot strange plotting

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I am struggling with strange behaviour of Oxyplot. I have a data, which has gap in the middle - there is bunch of them, than there is a gap, than they continue. I would expect, that Oxyplot will connect those two edge points, maybe with some small interpolation, but what is happening instead is quiet strange, see in the picture. Could you suggest where could be the hook?

Thanks.

[image: Those zigzag lines are strange]

Comment: I don't know about the others, but I don't really see/understand the problem... Maybe explaining a little more? Adding some annotations to the picture you added? Posting your expected plot? Writing some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after turning off smoothing, the problem went away.